# DID_RECOVER server-to-server notification during Sandbox testing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm testing an auto-renewable subscription using a Sandbox account and observing the server-to-server notifications that are received during one purchase cycle (initial purchase, auto-renewals, expiration of a single in-app purchase product).

Logs of the `notification_type` of each notification that is received:

```
INITIAL_BUY // initial purchase
DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS
DID_RENEW // first renewal
DID_RENEW // second renewal
DID_RENEW // third renewal
DID_RENEW // fourth renewal
DID_RECOVER // why does this happen?
DID_RENEW // fifth (last) renewal
DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS // auto-cancellation in sandbox mode
```

I tried this process repeatedly with different Sandbox testers and noticed the same behavior. Is there an explanation for why the `DID_RECOVER` notification is received each time?

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that you get that notification, for 2 reasons:

1. It is a notification related to billing issues
2. According to the documentation, this notification is not available in Sandbox

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type

[Test Notification Events with Sandbox (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYJar.png)